# iOS - UIViewcontroller detect rotation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, orientation

I am using `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` to detect rotation and move items according to the orientation.

The problem is that when the page first loads this method doesn't get called so it doesn't try to move the objects to the correct location?

What is the solution?

Comment: Are you trying to restrict it to a certain orientation? Such as having it launch in landscape mode, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manually detected the `UIInterfaceOrientation` from my `UIApplication`, and I manually called `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` on `viewDidAppear`

Answer (score 2):

You need to setup the interface according to the orientation

```
if ([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait)  {
     // do something
} else if ([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
     // do something else
}
```

And repeat that for al the different device orientations

Comment: actually UIInterfaceOrientation is the right way to handle orientation